# How did Hartley Rathaway know about Wells being The Reverse Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In The Flash season 1 episode 11 Hartley Rathaway says he knows Wells’ secret (about him being The Reverse Flash):

> Barry: Looks like you're not as smart as everyone says.
>
> Hartley Rathaway: Smart enough to have figured out who Harrison Wells really is. You see, I know his secret.
>
> That was for you, Flash. Feels good to have the great Harrison Wells behind you, doesn't it? But one day, this man will turn on you... [laughs] In a flash... And even you won't see it coming. I only hope that he leaves you in better shape than he left me. If you're lucky, you'll only be dead.
>
> [laughs] I almost forgot... I told your pet I know your deep, dark secret, Harrison. Have fun letting him in on that one.

He even saw Wells on the floor with his legs vibrating.

> Hartley Rathaway:Tell me, Harrison. Am I still you guy?

I’m confused. How did Hartley Rathaway know about Wells being The Reverse Flash?

Comment: I'd say something about spoilers in the question, but I figured it out watching the first episode and they practically wave a banner throughout the show about it, one of the reasons I gave up on the show being them taking so long to actually get to it.

Comment: What do you mean

Answer (score -1):

I thought the deep dark secret was Wells knowing that the particle accelerator was likely to fail dramatically in some way, and proceeding to turn it on anyway.